# Please help out for the below code for combobox properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have three comboboxes, with same values for all.

Here is the Code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(e){

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var value = this.value;

        $("select option").each(function(){

            var idParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
   
            if(id != idParent){
                if(this.value == value){
                    this.disabled = true;
                }
                
                else if($("#box_g1 option:selected").val()!="Default"){
                    $("#box_g2").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#box_g3").prop("disabled", false);
                }else{
                    $("#box_g2").prop("disabled",true).val('Disabled');
                    $("#box_g3").prop("disabled",true).val('Disabled');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="n1" id="box_g1">
    <option value="Default">Default</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select name="n2" id="box_g2" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select name="n3" id="box_g3" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Problem i am getting :

1. when i select value 'A' from combobox1 and then select value 'B' from combobox1 (from same combobobox), the value in combobox2 disabled value should be 'B' not 'A'. Same behaviour is for combobox3.
2. If we select, value 'Default' from combobox1, then all the combobxes should reset with default values and also combobox2 and combobox3 with 'Disabled' attribute.

Please help.

Comment: No.. its not the requirement...

Comment: If value 'A' is selected. then 'A' is disabled in other combobox. and if 'Default' is selected in Combobox1 then it should disable combobox1 and 2 and reset all the comboboxes with default values and enable all the values tooo.. which were disabled.. 
Is that ok Now ???

Comment: @sanki . Did you find any solution. Alex Filatov : has given solution upto some extent. Please check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/xyzky0h2/

Comment: @sanki no its not valid. Can you check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/haLdcvr5/ But, it needs some more enhancements ...

Comment: next requirement is to get the selected value from desired drop down-list and disable it, and if next value is selected from the same drop down-list, then previous value is enabled in the other comboboxes i.e. only the last value is disabled from the other drop down-list.

Comment: @sanki it is ok and resolves the issue but added 1 more issue : 
if i select 'A' from box1, 'B' from box2, then 'A' and 'B' both must be disabled in box3.. which was working find in the previous fiddle you can check ..

Comment: yes .. it is like that..

Comment: One more issue check the fiddle you provided. If we select 'A' from box1 and 'B' from box3, then 'A' and 'B' both must be disabled also in box2. i.e. box2 is dependent on box1 and box3 too, which was working fine with the fiddle i have provided.

Comment: No its still not ok, b'coz 'Disabled' gets disabled. The previous fiddle was better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("select ").change(function (e) {
   if ($("#box_g1").val() != "Default") {
      var ind = $("#box_g1 option:selected").index();
      $("#box_g3 option:eq("+ind+")").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#box_g2 option:eq("+ind+")").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#box_g2 option").not(":eq("+ind+")").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#box_g3 option").not(":eq("+ind+")").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#box_g3, #box_g2").prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
      $("#box_g2, #box_g3").prop("disabled", true).val('Disabled');
   }
 });
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyzky0h2/7/)

Comment: No... The requirement is different. When i select 'A' in combobox1, why 'C' gets selected in combobox1 and 2..